# Execute a bean action on page load using JSF2 and richFaces4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Im working on a `JSF2` and `richFaces4` application and I want to execute a backing bean action on load of one of my `xhtml` view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a bean `@ViewScoped`, a method with a `@PostConstruct` annotation will be invoked exactly once when rendering an xhtml view that references it.

For example:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Foo {
  @PostConstruct
  public void onPageLoad() {
  ...
  }
}


<h:outputText value=#{foo.property}"/>
```